# Install qpid-tool

Tags: ubuntu, centos

Does anyone know how to install qpid-tool on ubuntu/centOS?

http://www.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_MRG/1.1/html/Messaging_User_Guide/sect-Messaging_User_Guide-Command_Line_Tools-Using_qpid_tool.html

Can't fing binary files or anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about that tool.  However, looking at the doc you link to, and going back two pages, I see:

```
 yum groupinstall "MRG Management"
```

You need to start there.